# Fairly involved debugging of a VBA searching function in Excel, not sure where the issue is

Tags: vba, excel, search

I've been working on a searching function for Excel documents using a VBA macro. I had it working just before I made some changes that added the ability to identify cells already queried so I can include an "Others" column in my results for cells that didn't match any of the search terms. I need this column to display the actual cell value, but all other results columns can just show cell addresses of cells that contain the search term.

Currently, my program opens a text file of the user's choosing that contains just search terms, line by line. The program reads the file correctly, as the results worksheet populates with the search terms correctly, but the results don't populate with any actual results. My code for all relevant parts of the program is below:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private inputString As String, strPath As String, strLine As String
Private resultsCol As Integer, numberofOccurrences As Integer, searchTerms As Integer, intResult As Integer
Private wsTest As Worksheet
Private dataChart As Chart

Sub List_based_word_query()

Dim targetRng As Range
resultsCol = 2
searchTerms = 0

'Create new worksheet for List Results
Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List Results")
On Error GoTo 0
If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "List Results"
End If

'Clear the List Results Sheet
Worksheets("List Results").Cells.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("List Results").ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intResult <> 0 Then
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Open strPath For Input As #1
    Line Input #1, strLine 'first line
    Do
        inputString = strLine  'inputString = first line
        Line Input #1, strLine 'second line
        numberofOccurrences = Single_word_occurrences(inputString, ColumnLetter(resultsCol))
        Sheets("List Results").Cells(2, ColumnLetter(resultsCol)).Value = numberofOccurrences
        resultsCol = resultsCol + 1
        searchTerms = searchTerms + 1
    Loop While EOF(1) = False
    inputString = strLine  'the loop exits when at the last word, so we have to run one more time
    Line Input #1, strLine 
    numberofOccurrences = Single_word_occurrences(inputString, ColumnLetter(resultsCol))
    Sheets("List Results").Cells(2, ColumnLetter(resultsCol)).Value = numberofOccurrences
    resultsCol = resultsCol + 1
    searchTerms = searchTerms + 1
End If
Close #1

Exit Sub
End Sub

Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Integer) As String 'This function takes the column number and converts it to a letter
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    n = ColumnNumber
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s
End Function

Function Others(startCell As Range, endCell As Range) As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    For i = startCell.Row To endCell.Row Step 1
        If startCell.Offset(0, i).Address = endCell.Address Then
            Others = i
            Exit Function
        End If
        Sheets("List Results").Cells(2 + i, ColumnLetter(1)).Value = endCell.Value
    Next
End Function

Function Single_word_occurrences(datatoFind As String, resultsCol As String) As Integer
    'Initializations
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim foundRange As Range, LastAddress As Range
    Dim currentSheet As Integer, sheetCount As Integer, LastRow As Integer, loopedOnce As Integer, FoundCount As Integer, numberofOthers As Integer

    loopedOnce = 0
    FoundCount = 0
    currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
    sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set foundRange = Range("F2:F30000").Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=Cells(2, 6), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    Msgbox(foundRange)
    Sheets("List Results").Cells(1, resultsCol).Value = datatoFind
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then 'if datatoFind is found in search range
        strFirstAddress = foundRange.Address 'strFirstAddress = address of first occurrence of datatoFind
        Do 'Find next occurrence of datatoFind
            Set foundRange = Range("F2:F30000").Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=foundRange.Cells, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            'Place the value of this occurrence in the next cell down in the column that holds found values (resultsCol column of List Results worksheet)
            LastRow = Sheets("List Results").Range(resultsCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("List Results").Range(resultsCol & LastRow).Value = foundRange.Address
            numberofOthers = Others(LastAddress, foundRange)
            Sheets("List Results").Cells(2, ColumnLetter(1)).Value = numberofOthers
            If loopedOnce = 1 Then
                FoundCount = FoundCount + 1
            End If
            If loopedOnce = 0 Then
                loopedOnce = 1
            End If
            LastAddress = foundRange.Address
            'The Loop ends on reaching the first occurrence of datatoFind
        Loop While foundRange.Address <> strFirstAddress And Not foundRange Is Nothing
    End If
    Single_word_occurrences = FoundCount
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets(currentSheet).Activate
End Function
```

The program runs without any errors. I'm assuming there is a logical error in the Single_word_occurrences function, but I can't for the life of me find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the cells not being populated, or are you getting the wrong numbers?

Comment: Why do you have `On Error Resume Next` before opening the file?  You should comment that out, and see what errors are generated that are currently being suppressed.

Comment: When commenting that line out no errors are given

Comment: I'm getting no results. I get a results sheet with the first row containing the search terms (courtesy of this line):

Sheets("List Results").Cells(1, resultsCol).Value = datatoFind

But past that I get no results underneath those terms where there should be cell addresses of queried cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this

```
 Sheets("List Results").Cells(2, ColumnLetter(1)).Value = numberofOthers
```

in Single_word_occurrences, should be

```
Sheets("List Results").Cells(1, 2).Value = numberofOthers
```

if search terms are i.e in column A and numberofothers in ColumnB. If they are in same column, data will be overwritten.

Comment: Currently my code puts the search terms in Row 1, starting in Column B to leave room for Others in Column A. This line puts the number of cells that are "others", i.e. not cells that match any of the search terms, in Row 2, Column A. Your suggestion would put number of "others" in the column past resultsCol, which is constantly being updated throughout the program. If I did that it would overwrite actual results.

Comment: So the row 1 is populated like this(?):
[empty] [search1] [result1] [search2] [resullt2] ... etc?

Comment: Only Row 2, Column A is populated with that number. Column A is for results in the "Others" function

Comment: The Others function return a result only if a value equals last cell value in range and then exits. Is this what you want?

Comment: The Others function should step through the row numbers between the LastAddress variable, which holds the range of the last cell in which the keyword is found, and the foundRange variable, which holds the range of the current found cell in which the keyword is found. Once they equal each other the program exits. This takes any cells in between values of foundRange that the program identifies and puts their values in the Others column, column A.